# Eigen giving different results for inplace versus non-inplace versions of function

Tags: c++, eigen

I am having a weird problem where two functions that should give identical results are disagreeing. I have included the code below. I know that the results of `test1` are correct while `test2` are wrong.

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::MatrixXd test1(Eigen::MatrixXd A){
  int p = A.rows();
  return A.triangularView<Eigen::Lower>().solve(Eigen::MatrixXd::Identity(p,p)).transpose();
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::MatrixXd test2(Eigen::MatrixXd A){
  int p = A.rows();
  Eigen::MatrixXd I = Eigen::MatrixXd::Identity(p,p);
  A.triangularView<Eigen::Lower>().solveInPlace(I);
  A.transposeInPlace();
  return A;
}


/*** R
A <- rWishart(1, 10, diag(4))[,,1]
A <- t(chol(A))

test1(A)
test2(A)
*/
```

Here is the output

```
> test1(A)
          [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]
[1,] 0.2251857 -0.01455544 -0.20205410 -0.08993337
[2,] 0.0000000  0.32498583 -0.06486972 -0.14006616
[3,] 0.0000000  0.00000000  0.60379357  0.27294390
[4,] 0.0000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.37409978

> test2(A)
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]        [,4]
[1,] 4.440779 0.1988932 1.5074352  0.04220045
[2,] 0.000000 3.0770572 0.3305895  0.91087781
[3,] 0.000000 0.0000000 1.6561952 -1.20836313
[4,] 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000  2.67308367
```

My question is how do I write an inplace version of `test1` that is not incorrect? Also why is `test2` incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
A.triangularView<Eigen::Lower>().solveInPlace(I);
```

modifies `I` not `A`. So you need to ends `test2` with:

```
I.transposeInPlace();
return I;
```